# jQuery $('a') not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is probably fairly simple but I've really tried every combo I could think (and Google) on how to fix this but nothing worked at all.

I've got this block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').not("div.thatguy a, div#thisguy a").click(function(event) {
        // do things
    });
});
```

What's weird is that it's not selecting the links properly (?!).

What I want is for it to apply to every link except those inside div.thatguy and div#thisguy .

What's happening now is that it's applying to these kind of links:

- domain.com/about/
- domain.com/that/
- domain.com
- domain.com/example/

But it doesn't want to work with these links:

- domain.com/2010/check/
- domain.com/2009/post/
- domain.com/2012/thing/

It's also *not* ignoring the links I want it to ignore.

Help?

*edit*:  I just realized something that might be the reason why the other links aren't working. The first batch of links (which work) are in a  while the second batch of links (which don't work) are in an  which gets loaded and replaced via AJAX links. Is it possible that the jQuery doesn't get applied to those?

*edit 2*: This seems to have worked. I didn't realize the AJAX content would have affected the script. Sorry!
`$('a').not("div.insertedimg a, div#thisguy").on('click', function(event) {`

Comment: what html are you using?

Comment: Please post your HTML structure and possibly a JSfiddle.

Comment: @SamJones Sorry, I'm not sure how I can compress the HTML for a suitable fiddle. It's for a WordPress setup with pages and posts.

Comment: ok, but without providing any html we're kind of shooting in the dark...

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/salman/NL8W6/

Comment: @SamJones I'll try putting one together, though I'm not sure if it'll be an exact duplicate since it's spread over several pages.

Comment: @SamJones I just realized something that might be the reason why the other links aren't working. The first batch of links (which work) are in a <nav> while the second batch of links (which don't work) are in an <article> which gets loaded and replaced via AJAX links. Is it possible that the jQuery doesn't get applied to those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').not("div.thatguy a").not("div#thisguy a").click(function(event) {
        // do things
    });
});
```

Or,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a:not("div.thatguy a"):not("div#thisguy a")').click(function(event) {
        // do things
    });
});
```

---

I'm taking jsfiddle of @Salman A [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NL8W6/3/)   |   [updated demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/NL8W6/4/) which are working.

---

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Example:

```
// attach a directly bound event
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});

// attach a delegated event
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, no dice :( edit: the second block resulted in nothing working

Comment: there was space between :not selector. updated. try now.

Comment: Tried, still nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Thank you for trying D:

Comment: place your html by inspecting then.

Comment: I may have figured it out, I'm so sorry. I didn't realize the fact that the second block of links were loaded via AJAX might have been affecting it. I had to use `$('a').not("div.insertedimg a, div#thisguy").on('click', function(event) {` which ended up working

Comment: Oh! so you need to use event delegation method

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a:not(div.thatguy a, #thisguy a)', function(event) {
        // do things
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I needed to use .on()